# Resistor in high frequency

Tags: resistors, high-frequency

Can we use a simple resistor of any kind, with resistance of 1.2 kΩ in high frequency like 4 GHz?

Comment: Welcome! Have you looked into ESL for simple resistors? What impedance will that ESL have at 4 GHz?

Answer (score 2):

[Typical shunt capacitance](https://www.vishay.com/docs/60107/freqresp.pdf) of a 0201 or 0402 resistor is in the range of 0.02pF or above.

If you work out the effect of that you’ll find it’s quite significant for a relatively high value resistor such as 1.2k ohms at 4GHz.

You can work out the effect of the inductance as well.

Inductance has more effect on small values of resistance, and capacitance has more effect on high values of resistance.

Answer (score 0):

No, definitely not any kind.

At least a wirewound resistors would be a terrible idea at 4 GHz, as it's simply a coil of wire. Most likely many other types of resistors will be unsuitable too.

Answer (score 0):

For GHz range resistors it is better to use smaller SMT film types. As with many other high frequency parts there are specially made resistor types that are recommended for the GHz ranges, such as [these from Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/en/resistors-fixed/high-frequency/) and [some others](https://www.viking.com.tw/en/category/Resistor-ARF.html). Notice that in the actual datasheets the higher value resistances and larger body sizes show higher Z/R characteristics.